# google spreadsheets - filter a cell by it's address

Tags: google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I am using the filter function to find non blank values, the classic:

```
=FILTER(A2:A99, NOT(ISBLANK(B2:B99)))
```

To find all the column A headings that have a non-blank value in column B.

But I would also like to always include the last value regardless of it's ISBLANK, something like:

```
=FILTER(A2:A99, (CELL("address",A2:A99)="$A$99") OR NOT(ISBLANK(B2:B99)))
```

But this gives me an error, leading me to the strange question of how do I get this to work:

```
=FILTER(A2:A99, CELL("address",A2:A99)="$A$99")
```

Or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `CELL` function does not play well in array formulas, you can get addresses as strings for cells like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ADDRESS(ROW(A2:A99), COLUMN(A2:A99)))
```

[image]

As for your original problem, you can just add the last cell as the last row:

```
={FILTER(A2:A98, NOT(ISBLANK(B2:B98))); A99}
```

Or a dynamic version:

```
=FILTER(A2:A99, (NOT(ISBLANK(B2:B99))) + (ROW(A2:A99) = (ROWS(A2:A99) + ROW(A2) - 1)))
```

[image]